# Recurring HDD led blinking every 2 seconds in ext4

Tags: linux, hard-drive

I've installed a new motherboard and then I've noticed the HDD led is blinking every 2 seconds.
That just freaked me out! Why this recurring disk activity?
I was thinking my HDD was in constant use even with data=writeback and commit=60! smartctl doesn't helped me to figure it out! Tried to configure APM and others, nothing helped!

These links, and others, doesn't have any clues either:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=174729
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=212854

Please help! What may be causing this?

Thanks!

P.S.: I'm posting this for future reference. It took me 2 weeks to solve.

Answer (score 1):

I took me 2 weeks to find out that this was DVD polling.
My DVD is sata and when linux tries to see if there is any disk inserted, the led blinks.
I've removed the DVD cable and the led blinking stopped.

I could not find any command to increase polling time.
At least I know my HDD is safe.